# How to extract the specific data from the unorganized excel file without columns)

Tags: python, pandas, glob

I reached my limit and My hair is getting thinner.
I really need your help.

**1. Try**

I'd like to extract the data line including the specific words "**Super Banana**" from `*.xlsx` in one folder.

Here is the file pic.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cb3yD.png

But

**2. Problem**

- No columns in this unorganized excel files. There are many files and
  I can`t add column manually to all files.

  I was looking for the way to extract:

1. the row including the key words "**Super Banana**"

   or
2. the row before and after the row including the key words

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cb3yD.png

- A1 title "Monday Shopping List 2020 " will be changed (Monday
  Shopping List 2020,Monday Shopping List 2021...)

**3. My Code**

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('*.xlsx')
print(files)

import pandas as pd
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_excel(file).fillna(value = 0)
    for row in df.values:
        data = df[df[''].str.contains('Super Banana',na=False)]
        data.to_excel('excel-data_find.xlsx', encoding='utf-8')
        print(data)
        print('Data was extracted')
```

Comment: Please dont post images of your data. Add a minimum viable data-set so people can work with it.

Comment: thank you for your comment. but It's not included my important data.

Answer (score 0):

use the proper file path.
Example :
`df = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\file.xlsx').fillna(value = 0)`

Comment: Thank  you for your comment.path is no problem . It's in the same directory.the problem  is the empty column  I don't want to add column manually.because there are too mamy files. any solution ?